# How to import programmally a private key in the local machine keystore?

Tags: c#, cryptography, windows-7-x64, private-key

How to import programmally a private key in the local machine keystore?

Actually I'm testing this code:

```
    private static void InstallCertificate(string certificatePath, string certificatePassword, StoreName store) {
        try {
            var serviceRuntimeUserCertificateStore = new X509Store(store, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            serviceRuntimeUserCertificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

            X509Certificate2 cert;

            try {
                cert = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to load certificate " + certificatePath);
                throw new DataException("Certificate appeared to load successfully but also seems to be null.", ex);
            }

            serviceRuntimeUserCertificateStore.Add(cert);
            serviceRuntimeUserCertificateStore.Close();
        } catch(Exception) {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to install {0}.  Check the certificate index entry and verify the certificate file exists.", certificatePath);
        }
    }
```

All tries to get the NetworkService token failed yet. The code [here](http://geek.hubkey.com/2008/02/impersonating-built-in-service-account.html) doesn't work with admin privileges.

The code above imports the private key to the currient user instat of the local machine. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN has a [solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950090). Simply add a flag `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` and it runs fine:

```
cert = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath,
                            certificatePassword,
                            X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```